# My function works in practice but does not pass tests rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd, ruby-test

Perhaps it is my lack of familiarity with rspec but i do not understand what is going on with my test.

I have 2 classes one called Scrape, the other Result (creative) Scrape is a web scraping class that searches a site and scrapes the results from the page, creating a new Result instance from each.

Result instances are stored in a class variable array accessible via Result.all

this works in practice in the actual program, however when I tried to write a test for this behavior it fails.

```
    describe "#scrape_results" do
        it "accepts a url scrapes the page and creates a Result for each" do
            s = Scrape.new
            s.scrape_results(@url)
            expect(Result.all.count).not_to eq(0)
        end
    end
```

every time i run the test Result.all.count is 0
if i use pry and manually run #scrape_results the test passes.

I appreciate your time, patience, and help
thanks

Comment: Do you have stubs or anything? Can you put a breakpoint in your `scrape_results` method and figure out why the record is not created?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are passing `@url` to `#scrape_results` in your test. Unless you are defining that variable inside of the describe block or the test block it will be `nil` in your test. It is possible that since `@url` might be something other than `nil` from wherever you are pry-ing which is causing the Result to be created and the test to pass.